# How to Disable Effect on Form Open/Close in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, transition, effect

I'm trying to make a program where there are multiple forms. Now what I would like to accomplish is that, whenever I open another form, the current form will close but I would like to do that without the forms having to vanish with an effect. Is there a way in the properties to do that? I tried changing the DoublBuffered into TRUE but it has no effect (I mean, the effect was still there). Can somebody point me to the right direction please? Thanks in advance. :D

By the way, I'm using:

```
Form2.Show()
Me.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out, but you can use the following. Assuming you have 2 Forms(1,2)

```
private void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventLog e)
{
    if((bool)Form1.ActiveForm)
    {
    Form1.Visible = true;
    Form2.Visible = false;

    // Rest of your code to display

    }
    if((bool)Form2.ActiveForm)
    {
    Form1.Visible = false;
    Form2.Visible = true;

    // Rest of your code to display

    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you had tried it out, you'd have found that it doesn't even compile, let alone do what the question asked.

Comment: Question is tagged `vb.net`!

Comment: Ofcourse it doesn't works. you can't use form1 in form1. Use Me. instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
Form1.Opacity = 0
```

Here are places to add it. First set Form 2 opacity as 0 in visual studio. and then go to the form load and after loading all the things you need put in,

```
Form2.Opacity = 100
```

Then before form 1 closing put in,

```
   Me.Opacity = 0
```

You just need to know where to set to 0 and where to 100. It will work good. But I am not sure why you don't want that effect.